# Linking NFTs of two contracts

Tags: tokens, nft

Is it possible to link two NFTs?

Say I have an NFT from Smart Contract A, and another NFT from Smart Contract B, can I link an NFT of A to an NFT of B?

Comment: what do you mean by link in your terms

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

But more information would be needed to give a good answer. Why not if you can define what you mean by "link"? You can program whatever you want to.

It sounds like you want to say, "given one NFT from collection A, I want to point to another NFT at collection B"?

You can do this in many ways. One possible way could be to create a smart contract that stores the NFT collections and internally tracks this mapping, e.g.:

```
mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => mapping(address => uint256))) mapAtoB;
```

The map (if you want A to B -- but you can just have another map also doing the reverse) is:
(address of the NFT collection A) -> (the specific token id/NFT within A) -> (address of the NFT collection B) -> (the specific token id/NFT within B)

But your question is open-ended. A good (and correct) implementation here would depend significantly on the use case.

Comment: What I want to do is make my PC with it's essential details as an NFT. Then in another Smart Contract, make certain softwares ans NFTs. Then I want to point like My PC has these softwares and link the softwares to the PC.

Comment: Yes you can do that, no problem.